# Gradle Jar Compression

Tags: jar, gradle

Is there a way to get Gradle to NOT compress the files when using the "jar" task?

I can't for the life of me find any reference to setting the compression settings for a jar.

Answer (score 7):

This may only be in the newer version of gradle, but you can now specify [`entryCompression`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:entryCompression) for your `jar` task:

> `ZipEntryCompression entryCompression`
>
> The compression level of the entries of the archive. If set to ZipEntryCompression.DEFLATED (the default), each entry is compressed using the DEFLATE algorithm. If set to ZipEntryCompression.STORED the entries of the archive are left uncompressed.

Answer (score 2):

Gradle's Jar task doesn't currently support any compression options. To generate an uncompressed Jar, use the Ant task.